# R,ncdf and clim.pact compatibily for Windows

Tags: r

My final goal it to install the `clim.pact` package in R. THis requires the `ncdf` package which is not available in this 3.5.1 R version anymore. My options are 2.

1. Download the clim.pact package and replace the ncdf -related functions with ncdf4 functions. I have found that the the ncdf functions that I should replace are `cdfextract.R` and `retrieve.nc.R` but Im not sure with which functions of ncdf4 I have to replace them.

2.Find a combination of older R version compatible with both the `ncdf` and `clim.pact` packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this combination of old versions of R and packages. They works on my windows 7 PC:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] clim.pact_2.3-10 akima_0.6-2      devtools_1.13.5  ncdf_1.6.8      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] curl_3.2        digest_0.6.14   grid_3.1.3      httr_1.3.1      lattice_0.20-30 memoise_1.1.0  
 [7] R6_2.2.2        sp_1.2-7        tools_3.1.3     withr_2.1.2
```

Comment: installed indeed. Thanks a lot